# Why would kubectl logs return Authorization error?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, k3s

I am trying to get logs from a pod that is running using `kubectl logs grafana-6bfd846fbd-nbv8r`
and I am getting the following output:

```
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: Authorization error (user=kube-apiserver, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)
```

I tried to figure why I would not have this specific authorisation even though I can manage everything with this user, no clue. The weirdest is that when I run `kubectl auth can-i get pod/logs` I get:

```
yes
```

After a few hours of going through ClusterRoles and ClusterRoleBindings, I am getting stuck and do know what to do to be authorized. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure is kube-apiserver trying to access the kubelet, not related to your user. This indicates your core system RBAC rules might be corrupted, check if your installer or K8s distro has a way to validate or repair them (most don't) or make a new cluster and compare them to that.

Comment: I tried running a brand new k8s cluster and a fresh installation of the OS. I get the same error. I am running k3s on two Raspberry Pi4 with Ubuntu Server 20.04 64 bit.

Comment: Retrying `kubectl logs <pod>` after a few minutes worked. No clue why but it worked. Thanks!